# Remove child element if being "cut" by parent element with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I am making a page where there should be **content on the left side** and **commercials in divs on the right side**. The height of the left sides div is unknown. I want to add as many commercial divs as possible on the right side without making the height of the right side taller than the left side.

I have set the right sides div height equal to left sides height and then I have added `overflow: hidden` on the right sides div so that the commercial divs are being cut off. I don't want my commercial divs to be cut off so I would like to remove the one that is being cut off.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/p9dmzoa3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, this will remove all those commercials DIV, which are getting cut-off :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".right_side").css("height", $(".left_side").height());
   $commercialDivs = $(".right_side").children("div.commercials");
   $rightSideDivHeight = $(".right_side").height();
   $tempHeight = 0;
   for(var i=0;i<$commercialDivs.length;i++){
        $tempHeight += $commercialDivs[i].clientHeight;
    if($tempHeight>$rightSideDivHeight){
        $commercialDivs[i].remove();
    }
   }   
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked great if I didn't add more content. https://jsfiddle.net/v5avmjs4/

Comment: That's because while calculating tempHeight, I haven't consider margin of 10px for commercials div. Please add 10 to it and it will work. i.e. `$commercialDivs[i].clientHeight+10`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the thing.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".right_side").css("height", $(".left_side").height());
   var j =  $(".right_side").children("div").length;
   
   for (var i = 1; i < j; i++) {
       if ((($('.right_side').offset().top + $(".right_side").height()) - ($('.right_side div:last-child').offset().top + $(".right_side div:last-child").height())) < 0) {
        $(".right_side div:last-child").remove();
       } else {
            break;
       }
   }
 });
```

```css
div.left_side {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.right_side {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.left_side_content {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

div.commercials {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" style ="width: 430px; background-color: lightblue;   padding: 5px;">

  <div class="left_side" style ="width: 200px; background-color: tomato;           padding: 5px;">
    <div class="left_side_content">content</div>
    <div class="left_side_content">content</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right_side" style ="width: 200px; background-color: orange;           padding: 5px;">
    <div class="commercials">commercials</div>
    <div class="commercials">commercials</div>
    <div class="commercials">commercials</div>
    <div class="commercials">commercials</div>
    <div class="commercials">commercials</div>
    <div class="commercials">commercials</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This worked good if i didn't add more commercials. Adding more commercial divs made it not work again. https://jsfiddle.net/bg7yfabp/

Comment: Wupsie, https://jsfiddle.net/bg7yfabp/1/ this works well. I've forgot to save the index()